# UILabel font size and color won't change

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, xcode7

I have a custom UITableViewCell that contains a UILabel.  There is a strange bug where if I set the numberOfLines to anything other than 1 on the UILabel, it won't acknowledge font change or textColor change.  If it is 1, it will.

Alternatively, if the text set for the UILabel is within one line, it will work as well.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you're creating all this in storyboard? it must not happen. you might be doing something wrong. btw, which version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Can you reproduce it at the smallest project created from a template with only a label added and minimal changes ?

Comment: @FayzaNawaz Xcode 7 and nib.

Comment: @A-Live Good idea, may have to go this route if I can't find the cause.  Strangest bug ever.

Answer (score 0):

Please call all your code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method! That works. I have many problems when changing font size, style in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear methods.

So just move your code in **viewDidLayoutSubviews** method. You can use flag to change fonts only once since this method can be called many times :]

Comment: I'm assuming you meant viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Comment: Yes, I made mistake somehow and now I correct to viewDidLayoutSubviews. Thanks for revision :)